# Error de CORS con gentritabazi01 / Clean-Laravel-Api

Tags: api, laravel-8, cors

Estoy montando una api con laravel basada en la estructura [gentritabazi01/Clean-Laravel-Api](https://github.com/gentritabazi01/Clean-Laravel-Api) y larapi. Es una api sencilla para el tratamiento de BBDD. El problema es que no consigo resolver el problema con el cors al hacer llamadas desde servidores distitntos. El problema que me aparece es el siguiente:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://dev.......com/users' from origin 'http://segu........com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Llevo 2 dias documentandome al respecto y ninguna de las soluciones me es valida. He probado creando un middleware propio y que añada las cabeceras necesarias y nada.

```
//Infrastructure\Http\Middlewares\Cors
    <?php
    use Closure;
    class Cors
    {
      public function handle($request, Closure $next)
      {
        return $next($request)
           //Url a la que se le dará acceso en las peticiones
          ->header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
          //Métodos que a los que se da acceso
          ->header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE")
          //Headers de la petición
          ->header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*"); 
      }
    }
```

He probado utilizando el paquete [Fruitcake](https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors) de laravel para hacer funcionar el cors, como también es utilizado en el el proyecto base de laravel y tampoco consigo hacerlos funcionar.

```
//Infrastructur/Http/Kernel.php
    class Kernel extends HttpKernel
    {
        /**
         * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
         *
         * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $middleware = [
            \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
            \Infrastructure\Http\Middlewares\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
            \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        ];
```

He probado poniendo las cabeceras a mano en el fichero index.php de la carpeta /public del proyecto y tampoco obtengo el resultado esperado.

```
//public/index.php
use Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset = UTF-8');
```

Estoy ya un poco desesperado y no se por donde más mirar. ¿Alguien que sepa como resolver? Si necesitais cualquier aporte más sobre el proyecto lo puedo adjuntar sin problema con tal de resolver esto.

Edit:
Añado el fichero config/cors.php por si sirve de ayuda:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Laravel CORS Options
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The allowed_methods and allowed_headers options are case-insensitive.
    |
    | You don't need to provide both allowed_origins and allowed_origins_patterns.
    | If one of the strings passed matches, it is considered a valid origin.
    |
    | If ['*'] is provided to allowed_methods, allowed_origins or allowed_headers
    | all methods / origins / headers are allowed.
    |
    */

    /*
     * You can enable CORS for 1 or multiple paths.
     * Example: ['api/*']
     */
    'paths' => ['*'],

    /*
    * Matches the request method. `['*']` allows all methods.
    */
    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    /*
     * Matches the request origin. `['*']` allows all origins. Wildcards can be used, eg `*.mydomain.com`
     */
    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    /*
     * Patterns that can be used with `preg_match` to match the origin.
     */
    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    /*
     * Sets the Access-Control-Allow-Headers response header. `['*']` allows all headers.
     */
    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    /*
     * Sets the Access-Control-Expose-Headers response header with these headers.
     */
    'exposed_headers' => [],

    /*
     * Sets the Access-Control-Max-Age response header when > 0.
     */
    'max_age' => 0,

    /*
     * Sets the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header.
     */
    'supports_credentials' => true,
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Finalmente, he encontrado una solucion. Borré todo lo relacionado con cors de mi proyecto y añadi lo siguiente en public/web.config:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Escribí esto dentro de la etiqueta "system.webServer" y todo funciona correctamente ahora.